# Animated tentacle collision / Rigid body not working

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I've created some IK rigged tentacles animated with noise modifiers :
(.blend file at the bottom)

[image]

I'd like to create some animated tentacles that uses the rigid body system so they don't go through each other, but instead collides with each other.

As you can see, i've set the tentacle geometry to Rigid Body with Active / Dynamic / Animated set for each of them.
Spheres are Rigid bodies / Active / Dynamic.

I have two problems :

-My spheres collides ok with one of the tentacles but the collision isn't really precise (there are some great gaps between the sphere and the tentacle). They don't seem to collide with the second tentacle.

-Tentacles don't collide with each other.

[image]

Comment: Being animated prevents them from being affected by physics.  They affect other objects, but their animation precludes any physics calculations from factoring into their movements.  One trick that probably isn't much use here is to animate them for a few frames and then uncheck the box (using keyframes) so that the physics system takes over.  This would probably result in them just flopping over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're animating them, they don't respond to physics, as earlier mentioned by Mutant Bob.

If you're looking for live animations, separate the tentacles so they can collide with each other. But if you use predetermined animations, this can glitch out on you.

To prevent each tentacle to collide with itself, you have to tweak the settings a bit to increase stiffness and apply self colliding.